# Can this summation be done without calculator?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Is it possible to perform the summation ,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^i}$$

without the use of calculator?

It does converge to a finite value = 1.29129...

[Wolfram Alpha link to this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%201%2F%28i%5Ei%29%20from%20i%3D1%20to%20inf)

Describe the method you would use to do this?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that there's a closed from for this.

Comment: Start adding terms. You get within 5 decimal places after just five terms. The convergence only grows more quickly from there.

Comment: It could possibly be rewritten using logs.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: The sum is the [sophormore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream). Aside from the famous identity $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n} = \int_0^1 x^{-x} dx$, not much is known about it (well, [someone](https://max.pm/notes/sophomores_dream.php) do have computed more than million digits of it using computer)

Comment: The query [series i^-1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+i%5E-i) returns $$1-i\log i+\frac12i^2\log^2i-\frac16i^3\log^3i+\frac1{24}i^4\log^4i-\cdots$$

Comment: @achillehui your 2nd link has 404 not found. Is there another one?

Comment: @TymaGaidash the site seems to relocate it links, [this](https://max.pm/posts/sophomores_dream/) seems to work.